# Filter Blog data containing Multiple Tags with View Limit and Pagination in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, filter, pagination, react-hooks

All Right Developers,
Let's clear out the problem first.

1. The Data Structure is something like that-
   Every single blog will contain multiple tags. (attached a sample of one data)

   const link = process.env.PUBLIC_URL;
   const Data = [
   {
   id: 1,
   tags: [
   'Tech', 'Design', 'Virtual Staging', '3D Modelling'
   ],
   img: `${link}/vendor/images/partner.jpg`,
   title: `'Tech', 'Design', 'Virtual Staging', '3D Modelling`,
   avatar: `${link}/vendor/images/blogger.png`,
   writer: `Jhon Doe1`,
   text: `We specialize in transforming photos of vacant properties into beautiful, virtually staged homes that sells faster and for top dollar.`,
   slug: `${link}`,
   date: `24 September 2019`
   },
2. In the design is, there are some buttons (Red Marked). each button contains a tag value. on clicking the button, the whole **Data** const should be filtered and only show the blog containing that specific data. (Below is the design view)

[image]

3. Apart from that, there's pagination within the same page and per page view limitation.

[image]
[image]

**Filter The Data with Pagination and View Page Limitation.**

Answer (score 0):

Okay,
I'll use Hooks for these tasks.
Let's sliced Up the Component-

1. A file containing all data; (data.js)
2. Pagination Component; (pagination.jsx)
3. Blog Component; (blog.jsx)
   Lastly,
4. Parent Component; (Index.jsx)

Let's Start With Parent's component:

1.We'll need a bunch of hooks. For

- Fetching blog Data;

  `const [blog, setBlog] = useState([]);`
- Tracking Pages;

  `const [page, setPage] = useState(1); //default page is 1 (First Page)`
- View Limit of Per Page;

  `const [blogLimit, limitChange] = useState(15); // Default View Per page 15 items`

Let's Dive into development.

First, we'll need to fetch data after Rendering (useEffect)-

```
useEffect(() => {
    blogLoading(true);
    setBlog(Data); /* Data is imported from data.jsx; it contains all blogs; */
    blogLoading(false);  /* You can set a setTimeOut() callback function for testing the loading UI */
}, []);
```

Then, Let's complete the UI Components:

Buttons -

```
<ul className="navbar-nav filter_options ml-auto mr-auto">
    <li className='nav-item'>
        <button type='button' onClick={() => { if (Data.length !== blog.length) {
                                                        setBlog(Data);
                                                };
                                            }}
                                                className="nav-link">All</button>
                                        </li>
                                        {tags.map(c => <li key={c.id} className='nav-item'>
                                            <button
                                                type='button'
                                                onClick={() => {
                                                filtering(c.value)
                                            }}
                                                className="nav-link">{c.value}</button>
                                        </li>)}
                                    </ul>
```

Here, the **Tags** are imported from data.js; When someone will click the button, it'll execute the "filtering" function -

```
const filtering = (t) => {
    let rslt = [];
    Data.forEach((e) => {
        let value = e.tags.find((d) => {
                return d === t;
            });
        if (value) {
            return rslt.push(e);
        };
    });
    return setBlog(rslt)
};
```

After that, the View Limit should be developed-

```
<div className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <div className="form_sector options">
          <div className="input">
               <h6>
                Per Page
                </h6>
           </div>
       <select className="styled" defaultValue={blogLimit} onChange={limit}>
               <option value='5'>5</option>
               <option value='15'>15</option>
               <option value='25'>25</option>
       </select>
    </div>
```

Now the limit function -

```
const lastBlogIndex = page * blogLimit;
const firstBlogIndex = lastBlogIndex - blogLimit;
const currentBlogs = blog.slice(firstBlogIndex, lastBlogIndex);    
const limit=(n)=>{
        limitChange(n.target.value);
};
```

Based on the currentBlogs value, the Blogs will be rendered -

```
{Object.keys(currentBlogs)
       .map(b => <Blogger
                         key={currentBlogs[b].id}
                         date={currentBlogs[b].date}
                         slug={currentBlogs[b].slug}
                         text={currentBlogs[b].text}
                         writer={currentBlogs[b].writer}
                         avatar={currentBlogs[b].avatar}
                         title={currentBlogs[b].title}
                         img={currentBlogs[b].img}
                         loading={loading}/>)}
```

Now, what left is Pagination-

```
<Pagination
           totalBlogs={blog.length}
           currentPages={page}
           paginate={pageGo}
           blogPerPage={blogLimit}/>
```

The pageGo is a function-

```
const pageGo = (n) => {
        setPage(n);
};
```

lastly, Let's dive into the pagination component (pagination.jsx) to complete the task-

First, Let's destructure props -

```
const pagination = ({blogPerPage, totalBlogs, paginate, currentPages}) => {
let pageNumbers = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalBlogs / blogPerPage); i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
}
```

Map page number based on pageNumbers-

```
{pageNumbers.map(n => (
                <li
                    key={n}
                    className={n === currentPages
                    ? "page-item active"
                    : "page-item"}>
                    <button type='button' className="page-link" onClick={() => paginate(n)}>{n}</button>
                </li>
            ))}
```

About previous and next button-

```
<li className={currentPages === pageNumbers.length ? "page-item disabled" : "page-item"}>
    <button className="page-link arrows" type='button' onClick={() => paginate(currentPages+1)}>Next<span aria-hidden="true">
      <i className="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i>
    </span>
    </button>
</li>
<li className={currentPages > 1 ? "page-item" : "page-item disabled" }>
    <button className="page-link arrows" type='button' onClick={() => paginate(currentPages-1)} tabIndex="-1" aria-disabled="true">
          <span aria-hidden="true">
                        <i className="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-left"></i>
          </span>Previous</button>
</li>
```

I hope. There's Nothing Left.

[**To check The Full Project**-GitHub Repository](https://github.com/malinjr07/react-filtering)